# Why does the inner product or norm represents the variability of a random variable?

Tags: least-squares, regression-coefficients

I am studyng about the $R^2$ coeficient in a OLS regression.  I would like to understand the following statement: One measure of the variability of the dependent variable $y$ is the sum of squares:

$$y'y = \langle y,y \rangle = \sum_i^n y_i^{2}$$

I as a mathematician see this as a simple inner product and I can not understand the intuition of how this can represent the variability of y. Some help?

Answer (score 2):

Think of it this way, there is a one-to-one correspondence between

$$\sum_i^n y_i^2\quad \text{and}\quad \frac{1}{n} \sum_i^n y_i^2$$

The latter is clearly the average of $y_i^2$ which measures the magnitude of each $y_i$. Hence in some sense measures the measures the magnitude of the components of $\bf{y}$.

Since there is a one-to-one correspondence, $\bf{y^Ty}$ $=\sum_i^n y_i^2$ also measures the magnitude of the components of $\bf{y}$.

Since the components of $\bf{y}$ are not necessarily i.i.d we should note that the weak law of large numbers does not necessarily hold. This is simply a heuristic explanation.